# How to access the info.response object from outside nodemailer transport

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope, nodemailer

I am trying to create a log of sent mails including some other details and need to access the `info.response` object from the mail transporter in node, I have tried a number of things including trying to expose the `info.response` as a global variable but I cannot seem to access it. I want to send a mail using the  transporter then log some entry details and the `info.response` code in the same line of the log.txt file. The `resInfo` is not accessible outside of the transporter and the array `clientReminderCandidates[x][1]` isn't accessible from within the transporter.

index.js

```
            gm.clientReminders();
            // clientReminderCandidates made available

            if (clientReminderCandidates.length != 0) {
                for (x = 0; x < clientReminderCandidates.length; x++) {

                    const clientReminders = require('./sendClientReminders.js')
                    clientReminders.sendRemindClient();

                    const updateReminders = require('./updateClientReminderSent.js')
                    updateReminders.updateClientReminder();

                }
            }
            else { console.log("No client reminders to update") }
```

sendClientReminders.js

```
            module.exports = {
                sendRemindClient: function () {
                    var fs = require('fs');
                    fs.appendFile('logs/logs.txt', 'LOG Reminder sent to ' + clientReminderCandidates[x][10] + ' ' + resInfo + ' \r\n', function (err) { // cannot access resInfo outside transporter
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('Reminder Sent and Logged!');
                    });

                    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                        resInfo = info; // I tried to reassign the `info` var from the transport function above

                        if (error) {
                            console.log(resInfo); // but this does not pull in the `info` var
                            console.log(resInfo);
                            console.log(info.response); // I need to use this in the top function @ resInfo.
                            transporter.close();
                        } else {
                            console.log(error);
                            console.log(clientReminderCandidates); // array is available
                            console.log(clientReminderCandidates[x][1]); // cannot access these objects undefined
                            console.log('Reminder Sent and Logged!');

                            transporter.close();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

How can I access the info.response in order to use it in the `fs.appendfile` function to build my log entry including the response code?

Comment: You haven't shown how and where you try to access `resInfo`, but likely you are doing it before it got assigned in the asynchronous callback.

Comment: My apologies, I am trying to learn more about sync and async functions however I am trying to access `info` in `transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {` from the function above it. The `resInfo = info;` was part of my attempt to assign it from the above function. I will edit for clarity.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that, sorry. But no, you can never access things *before* they are assigned, so even in synchronous code the call above couldn't get the `resolveInfo` that was created below. You will need to move the `fs.appendFile(…)` call inside the `transporter.sendMail` callback, so that it runs once the mail is sent, not before the mail sending even is started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, indeed that was what I thought too but if I move it to inside then I get `undefined` for clientReminderCandidates[x][1] but the array is returnable when using `clientReminderCandidates`

Comment: Where do `clientReminderCandidates`, `x` and `mailOptions` even come from? It looks like you haven't posted your actual code.

Comment: My guess would be that you're having a [closure in a loop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572)

Comment: This is a module export to my main index.js, where I call the module from.

Comment: clientReminderCandidates is available for use when the module is loaded, it is created using another module using a map function. Whats strange for me that is if I use `clientReminderCandidates` I can get the entire array to log however as soon as I use `clientReminderCandidates[x][1]` I get `undefined`. I don't understand because I use the `clientReminderCandidates[x][1]` in the mailer options above successfully (removed from this for readability)

Comment: I think I must be missing something with passing variables between functions. Thank you

Comment: Indeed, you seem to be saying that they are global variables? At least `x` definitely should be passed as a parameter from where you call `sendRemindClient`.

Comment: Yes x is defined as this is all wrapped in a for loop.

Comment: What "all this"? The `module.exports =` assignment? Don't do that, it won't work. Put only the `sendRemindCall(…)` in a loop, and pass `x` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you, I have added more context to my code for reference. I do call ` clientReminders.sendRemindClient();` inside a for :)

Comment: Yes, it's just as I said. `x` is a global variable - don't do that. Pass it as a parameter, or even better, pass the whole `clientReminderCandidates[x]`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, do you mean for eg to rather define `x` like `var myVar = 0` due to other loops using the `x` global variable and causing problems? I don't quite understand about where I should I pass `clientReminderCandidates[x]` as a parameter, in the function? I will research function parameters more - thank you again

Comment: Yes, you should use `for (var x = 0; …)` in your loop, and you should use a function parameter for the `clientReminderCandidate` object

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, I found a great tutorial to refresh and go through a few times so will attempt my best. Much appreciated.